# Error with Pushwoosh cordova plugin on Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, pushwoosh

I just installed [Pushwoosh cordova plugin](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin) on my Ionic project and now I can't run the app on my device to test.

Here are the official [docs](https://www.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap)

If I run:
`ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --device --livereload`

I get:

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/media/ivan/SharedPartition/Trabajo/AnimaEdu/animaedu-mobile/platforms/android/src/com/pushwoosh/plugin/pushnotifications/PushNotifications.java:888: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6

            mainHandler.post(() -> webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+ url));
                                ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
1 error
 FAILED
27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
(node:18368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /media/ivan/SharedPartition/Trabajo/AnimaEdu/animaedu-mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/media/ivan/SharedPartition/Trabajo/AnimaEdu/animaedu-mobile/platforms/android/src/com/pushwoosh/plugin/pushnotifications/PushNotifications.java:888: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6
            mainHandler.post(() -> webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+ url));
                                ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

I don't understand the output.

Any ideas? Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple:

> Error cause --> lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6

You are using `JDK 1.6` while the code of this plugin need to compile on `JDK 1.8` or greater.

Comment: `$java -version` :  
`java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: `javac 1.8.0_144`

Comment: But your ionic environment does not refer this java -version.check ionic reffering to which version?

Comment: Yes but, I don't know how to do that.
When I run `ionic cordova run android` if I see on te top of the output it says:
`ANDROID_HOME=/home/ivan/Android
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
`

Comment: Did you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable as mentioned in Cordova instructions-https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#setting-environment-variables

Comment: Also check your path variable in environment variable

Comment: Yes, and I updated the jdk but it's the same.
`echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/`
and `echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/ivan/Android`, but it's rare. It started happening after I upgraded `"cordova-android"` in the project, and `"cordova-android-support-gradle-release"`. Also I upgraded cordova global to 8.0.0.
Before that it was working...

Comment: anyway I need to solve the sdk problem also because I can not use the pushwoosh plugin

Comment: Okey, deleting and reinstalling the java sdk solved the problem. I still having problems with this plugin but it's another issue. Thank you!

Comment: I was solved with the steps mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489813/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater-on-ionic/51507578#51507578