# Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater on Ionic

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, java-8, ionic3

I have an Ionic app which started to fail when I run:

```
ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --device --livereload
```

I get this error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/ivan/Android
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

My environment variables are:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-oracle/

echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/ivan/Android
```

My current versions:

```
java -version
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 10.0.2
```

Ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v6.14.3
    npm               : 4.6.1 
    OS                : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/ivan/Android

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

I don't know what's happening here. Any ideas?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: have you checked https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/68734

Comment: Thank you. It was solved downgrading java sdk to 1.8. I'm going to write the steps that solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome.your another question is also solved I think

Comment: I don't know. I'll attempt to reinstall the PushWoosh plugin in order to check that :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved this issue with the following steps:

I had the v10 of java's sdk. So I downgraded to v8.

- Uninstall my jdk with:
  `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java10-installer`
- Follow this [steps](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/) to install v8.
- Restored my global installation of cordova. It was in 8.0.0 and I restored it to `7.0.1` with the command: `sudo npm install -g cordova@7.0.1`.
- I restored my `"cordova-android":` to  `"^6.4.0"` (in my app),
- Deleted all the plugins in confix.xml.
- Deleted android platform: `ionic cordova platform remove android`.
- Remove dependencies and plugins: `rm -rf /node_modules /plugins`.
- Add android platform again: `ionic cordova platform add android`.
- Then run on device: `ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --device --livereload`.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Java JDK 1.8
Run this before export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
with